# Gnome terminal doesn't start from unity

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I try to start gnome terminal from launcher, nothing happens. except terminal Icon starts glowing for a few seconds and then nothing ....

But when I try to open it through urxvt, It starts without any kind of error or output.

Comment: Try start it from another terminal and check output.

Comment: @BlueManCZ Tried it in xterm and xfce4 terminal. no difference

Comment: Yes, but was there any warning or error message?

Comment: @BlueManCZ no difference ! no there was not any error message in urxvt nor in xterm or xfce terminal.

Comment: @BlueManCZ I just started it in i3wm. it worked perfectly. so the problem is unity (probably)

Comment: Yes, apparently. But I'm not Unity specialist, so I can't help.

Comment: Wait, it starts successful from all terminals, but from Ubuntu dash not?

Comment: @BlueManCZYes. it opens from xterm and from i3+dmenu. and xterm does open from unity

Comment: Install `alacarte`, find gnome-terminal launcher, open properties and tell me a command.

Comment: @BlueManCZ it is "/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server". and when I run it it gives this error "Failed to register: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Terminal'" when I set it to "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal" it starts fine.

Comment: Yes, yes.. Ok..

Comment: You must have an incorrect local copy of the `gnome-terminal.desktop`  file. See dupe. In your case, step 1 should do ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be problem with launcher command which starts aplication.

Install `alacarte`, run it, find gnome-terminal launcher, open properties and insert command which work for you into input for command. In your case `gnome-terminal` or `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`. Than save changes.

Comment: it worked. but I really want to solve the real problem. what is wrong with gnome-terminal-server ?? why it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but Debian. Here I have Gnome and in my gnome-terminal launcher there is default command `gnome-terminal`. Command `gnome-terminal-server` or any package with this name doesn't exist here. So you should wait for some Ubuntu guru.

Comment: @A.Esm.T `gnome-terminal-server` is the process name, `gnome-terminal` the command to run gnome-terminal.